# Check if a field is capitalized?

Tags: custom-field, captions, customization

I want to check the if the first letter of a field is capitalized.

Example:

If (First Name field) is capitalized {

Capitalized!

} else {

Not Capitalized!

}

Thanks

Thank you

Comment: not a specific wordpress question; possibly try the other suggestions, but with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$field = 'First Name';

if(ucwords($field) !== $field){
 // not capitalized

}else{
 // capitalized

}
```

see [`ucwords()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Comment: I ran your solution in a loop that goes through all the users, but the didn't want to use the else statement. And for some reason when I set $field = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'display_name', true); I get a list of all the users and this indicates that the field is not capitalized. It should only show the users with the "display_name" not capitalized. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: It seems to work now, but I used the "nickname" field instead of "display_name." I think because the display name is based on the nickname by default (dynamically) I wasn't able to tell if it was capital or not. Using a field with a preexisting value the function worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to check the first letter of each word -

```
if(ucwords($name) === $name) :
    { First letter is capitalised }
else :
    $name = ucwords($name);
endif;
```

Or you can use `ucfirst()` for only the first letter of the field.

If you know for sure that you wan't it in upercase though, you don't have to worry about the check, just run do `$name = ucwords($name);` and PHP wont do anything if it does not need to.

Comment: After running the your if statement, I get results that show that all of the users' field is not capitalized and I don't understand why is that...

Comment: Figured out the problem. I needed to use a field an existing value in it. I used the nickname instead of display_name (as I was using in my code). Thanks a lot.